# Pass argument into script when calling from CircleCI config yaml

Tags: bash, circleci

Like the title says; I am trying to pass an argument into the script when called from the circileci config YAML.

on the command line it would look like this

```
$ run_script_names.sh john
```

pretty simple stuff, in CircleCI I cannot get this to work as it keeps interpreting it as a command I have tried with quotes, without (single, double ) If I call just the script it works but I cannot pass anything into it.

```
command: | run_script_names.sh john
```

Please excuse YAML formatting in the example above

**My question summarized is**: how to pass args into a script called from circleCI

Comment: If it's only a single command, you don't need the pipe. I don't know if that would create a problem, though. And I don't have an MWE I can try things on.

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Did you ever figure out a solution?